# Xamarin.iOS for iOS16

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, upgrade, ios16

I have implemented an iOS app based on Xamarin.iOS.
Now I like to upgrade the app for iOS16.

There is a dev blog from Microsoft which says that Xamarin supports already iOS16:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-ios-16-android-13-updates/

Visual Studio and Xcode have been updated to the latest versions.
After all the updates I am able to debug the app on an iOS16 simulator.
But the installation of the .ipa file on an iPhone 8 with iOS16 fails with an error "unable to install the app - try it later".

I recognized that there was no update of the nuget package "Xamarin.Forms" which I had to update on earlier iOS upgrades (e.g. to iOS15).

Currently I am not yet able to migrate to .NET6 and .NET Maui.
Does anyone know how to upgrade an old Xamarin.iOS app to iOS16?

**Update:** The app runs on iOS16 but the installation by itms-services does not work. I cannot find any changes in Apples changelog.

Answer (score 0):

We used the wrong bundle identifier (bundle-identifier) in the manifest.xml for a long time. It looks like iOS15 ignored that mismatch but iOS16 blocks the installation. After adjusting the bundle identifier the installation worked well again.